Python debugging in vscode ends after 5 seconds of inactivity
I'm on Macbook Pro M4 Max, python 3.9.20 running in conda environment. I'm using vscode to debug the program, but when debugging, the child process dies after 5 seconds of not doing anything (a breakpoint lasts 5 seconds only):
my python program is launched using a script launch_proxy.py which launches a uvicorn instance serving my api.
import uvicorn
if __name__ == "__main__":
    workers = 6
    uvicorn.run("api.detection_proxy:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8184,workers=workers, reload=workers == 1, proxy_headers=True, forwarded_allow_ips="*")

and a launch.json in vscode:
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "launch_proxy.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/ppl_server",
        "env": {
            "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/opt/homebrew/lib/postgresql@14/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH",
            "PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL": "NO",
            "PYDEVD_TIMEOUT": "999999",
            "PYDEVD_DEBUG_LOG_DIR": "/tmp/debugpy_logs"
        },
    }
]
}

The program runs fine
But when it hits a breakpoint, if you don't do a step over or a step into within 5 seconds of reaching this breakpoint, the child process dies, and is restarted leaving me with an empty response, and no debugging whatsoever
As my launch.json suggests, I have tried many parameters and configs to circumvent the 5 seconds, I even tried listening for any signal in the launch_proxy.py file like this:
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print(f"Received signal: {sig}")
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

#this part is to print something that's how i knew a new child process has spawned
import os
print("PYDEVD_TIMEOUT:", os.environ.get("PYDEVD_TIMEOUT"))
print("PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL:", os.environ.get("PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL"))
print("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:", os.environ.get("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"))

The signal handler prints nothing when the child process dies
I tested the signal handler by issuing a ctrl + c, and i can see it prints signal 15 received
I should mention that a similar setup with the same versions of the pip packages works fine on my windows laptop
